# Pandas reading csv into hdfstore thrashes, creates huge file

Tags: pandas, pytables, hdfstore

As a test, I'm trying to read a small 25 mg csv file using pandas.HDFStore:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('file.h5',mode='w')
for chunk in read_csv('file.csv',chunksize=50000):
     store.append('df',chunk)
store.close()
```

It causes my computer to thrash and when it finally completes, file.h5 is 6.7 gigs. I don't know what is causing the file size to balloon: when I look at the store afterwards, the only thing in there is the small dataframe.
If I read the csv in without chunking and then add it to the store, I have no problems.

Update 1:
I'm running Anaconda, using python 2.7.6, HDF5 version 1.8.9, numpy 1.8.0, pytables 3.1.0, pandas 13.1, ubuntu 12.04. 
The data is proprietary, so I can't post the chunk information online. I do have some mixed types. It still crashes if I try to read everything in as object.

Update 2:
Dropped all the columns with mixed type and I'm still getting the same issue. I have some very large text columns if that makes any difference.

Update 3:
The problem seems to be loading the dataframe into the hdfstore. I drastically reduced the size of my file, but kept one of my very wide columns (1259 characters). Whereas the size of the csv file is 878.6kb, the size of the hdfstore is 53 megs. Is pytables unable to handle very wide columns? Is there a threshold above which I should truncate?

Comment: post the chunk.head() and chunk.dtypes. what version pandas, python, os, pytables?

Comment: that's the problem, everything should *not* be ``object`` dtype (unless its a string).

Comment: While my suggestion to add anonymization as a built-in pandas function was rejected, when dealing with proprietary data in a case like this you can always try replacing all integers with 0, all floats with 1.0, all strings with 'a', etc.  If the problem still occurs, then you've got a frame you can show us without violating confidentiality.  If it doesn't, then you've helped narrow down what's causing the problem.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the types at load time. Any way around this?

Comment: The type information can be accessed via `df.dtypes`, which is a `Series`, so (for example) `for col, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():` does what it looks like.

Comment: @DSM anonymization per se wasn't rejected :). just don't think it would help in the vast majority of cases as the issues are most often data driven.

Comment: You need to specifiy ``min_itemsize`` if you are storing in chunks, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#string-columns as the first chunks may not be representative of what is a fixed size column.

Comment: I gave `min_itemsize` a shot but it crashed my machine again.

Comment: w/o seeing your data set not clear how to help

Comment: The problem seems to be the very wide column. Would you still like me to post some of my data and datatypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wide object columns are definitely the problem. My solution has been to truncate the object columns while reading them in. If I truncate to a width of 20 characters, the h5 file is only about twice as large as a csv file. However, if I truncate to 100 characters, the h5 file is about 6 times larger.

I include my code below as an answer, but if anyone has any idea how to reduce this size disparity without having to truncate so much text, I'd be grateful.

```
store = pd.HDFStore(filepath, 'w')
for chunk in pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=5000, sep='\t',
                         na_values="null", error_bad_lines=False):

    chunk = chunk.apply(truncateCol)
    store.append(table, chunk)

def truncateCol(ser, width=100):
    if ser.dtype == np.object:
        ser = ser.str[:width] if ser.str.len().max() > width else ser
    return ser
```